# Splitting a table of integers in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Postgresql newbie here.

I have a table of integers that look like the following:

```
1950018111211111111111111
1940490521222211111111111
```

What i am trying to do is to `left` the above such that the first 7 numbers remain as one and the rest are split into something like the following with a serial number and the rest of the digits in the integer:

```
1 1950018 1
2 1950018 1
3 1950018 1
4 1950018 2...
.
.
19 1940490 5
20 1940490 2...
```

and so on. I know that we could use the `left()` function to split the first seven numbers but i do not know how to proceed after that. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following would do what you need:

```
SELECT
    row_number() over() as rownumber,
    intToRows.*     
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            left(field, 7), 
            unnest(string_to_array(right(field, length(field)-7) ,NULL))
        FROM
            table
    ) as intToRows
```

This uses `string_to_array` which will split a string into an array of values. We are claiming a delimiter here of `NULL` so that it will split each character. The `unnest` function takes that array and turns each element into a record.

The `row_number() over() as rownumber` bit adds the original numbering of the elements coming form the `intToRows` derived table into the output of the parent query to match your example. If that isn't need then you can probably just go with the subquery in the `FROM` clause and be done with it.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7eae7/2/0)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will satisfy you request:

```
SELECT 
       row_number() over () as no, text1, text2 
  FROM
       (SELECT substring(column1,1,7) as text1, 
               regexp_split_to_table(substring(column1,8),'|') as text2
          FROM 
               table
       ) AS temptable
```

The text "regexp_split_to_table(substring(column1,8),'|')" will split the text per character into a table. Or you can use another such as

```
regexp_split_to_table(substring(column1,8),'\\s*')
```

[PostgreSQL functions-matching](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html)